# How to Measure Latency in amazon media live streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, streaming, live, latency, flashmedialiveencoder

As per amazon blog
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/how-to-compete-with-broadcast-latency-using-current-adaptive-bitrate-technologies-part-1/

I read the document and understood different types of latency explained in the document. Now I am trying to calculate capture latency, but I am not able to calculate as per document.

Let me know if anyone has an idea about latency calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to measure latency is to capture the live broadcast time and compare it with the playback time - this is what the blog is trying to highlight with this diagram:

[image]

The suggestion in the blog is to use a clapperboard, but anything which gives a view of the time with enough precision should do. You then film the clappebboard, broadcast it through your live network however you have it set up and display the resulting live stream on a local device right beside the clapperboard.

If you now take a picture of the clapperboard beside the live broadcast of the clapperboard, the difference in times on the actual vs the broadcast clapperboard will be the latency.

Note that this is just telling you the end to end latency, not which element(s) in the chain are responsible for the latency.